# Applying filter to every photo in directory

Tags: python

I am new to python, so go easy on me!  I am trying to apply a blur to every .bmp image in a folder.  I am able to get the first half of the code to work, so the filter is applied to all the photos, but then I can't get it to re-save each image. I want to keep the original images, and add the new images to the folder. Here's what I have:

```
from PIL import Image from PIL import ImageFilter import os, fileinput, sys

##for every item in X folder that ends in X, apply a basic blur to the image##

for entry in os.scandir('/Users/kh'): 
    if entry.path.endswith('.bmp'):
        img = Image.open(entry.path)
        img = img.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(2))

        img.show()

        ##and then re-save each of those new images under a new filename##

        # Split our original filename into name and extension
        (name, extension) = os.path.splitext(filepath)

        # Save with "_blur" added to the filename
        img.save(name + '_blur' + extension)

        # Save the image as a BMP
        img.save(name + '.bmp')
```

I've tried a bunch of other stuff, but this code is the closest I've gotten.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: which save operation fails? The first or the second? Why do you need to save the original file? its already on disk - right?

Comment: This is the error I get: ValueError: unknown file extension.

Sorry for the confusion-- I don't need to save the original file, just keep the original file AND save a new file as "originalfile_blur"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code. I actually get:

> NameError: name 'filepath' is not defined

because you have a `filepath` which should be `entry.path`:

```
(name, extension) = os.path.splitext(entry.path)
```

Besides this, your code works, except that you have both images blurred. The last line:

```
img.save(name + '.bmp')
```

is cleary not needed, it overwrites the original images with the blurred ones.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Oh, wait! It works, but it keeps going infinitely so that when a new file_blur is added to the folder, it finds it as it continues to search the directory.  I've ended up with file_blur_blur and file_blur_blur_blur etc.  How do I tell it to stop in this case?

Comment: Nevermind.  Just added:     if entry.path.endswith('_blur'): break

Comment: Funny part, it did not happen to me. Maybe it is some system or version behaviour, I am not sure. I used python3.6 on linux. But you should not use `break`, you should use `continue`, I guess. Otherwise you may lose some images. Or are you looping over `os.scandir('/Users/kh')` more than once?

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 on MacOS.  I'll try `continue` instead.  Ideally I want to loop over the directory just once.